Get relation data from osmdata
Looking at OpenStreeMap underlying data I see that the data that I want is at the relation level and when I query the OSM using osmdata in R I cannot get this data.
https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/15019644
The code that I have is as follows:
  bbx <- getbb("Ireland")
  y <- bbx %>%
  opq(timeout = 25*100,osm_types = 'relation')%>%
  add_osm_feature("plant:source","wind") %>%
  osmdata_sf() 

I can get the osm_point data, but not the osm_relation data that aggregates, and joins the points.

osmdata_sf seems to transform only polygon and line relations, but you can get point relation data from xml response, transform it to data.frames / tibbles and, if needed, join to sf point object:
library(osmdata)
library(sf)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# Overpass response as XML
wind_xml <- 
  getbb("Ireland") |> 
  opq(timeout = 25*100,osm_types = "relation") |> 
  add_osm_feature("plant:source","wind") |> 
  osmdata_xml() 
# XML response to "regular" osmdata sf object 
wind_sf <- osmdata_sf(doc = wind_xml)

# find all relations with  `<member type="node" ... >` nodes,
# use realtion id as list names,
# from every relation find all node members, extract attributes (type, ref, role),
# turn named lists into frames with bind_rows,
# bind resulting frames, use list names for `relation` column
relation_nodes <- 
  xml_find_all(wind_xml, "//relation[member[@type='node']]") %>% 
  set_names(map(.,xml_attr, "id")) |> 
  map(\(x) xml_find_all(x, "./member[@type='node']") |> xml_attrs()) |> 
  map(bind_rows) |> 
  list_rbind(names_to = "relation")

relation_nodes
#> # A tibble: 2,578 × 4
#>    relation type  ref        role     
#>    <chr>    <chr> <chr>      <chr>    
#>  1 6949501  node  2616376676 generator
#>  2 6949501  node  2616376686 generator
#>  3 6949501  node  2616376653 generator
#>  4 6949501  node  2616376627 generator
#>  5 6949501  node  2616376638 generator
#>  6 6949501  node  2616376608 generator
#>  7 6949501  node  2616376612 generator
#>  8 6949501  node  2616376595 generator
#>  9 6949501  node  2616376588 generator
#> 10 6949501  node  2616376560 generator
#> # ℹ 2,568 more rows

# similar aporach as before, but now extract all tag elements,
# pivot wider, tag keys to columns
relation_tags <- 
  xml_find_all(wind_xml, "//relation[member[@type='node']]") %>% 
  set_names(map(.,xml_attr, "id")) |> 
  map(\(x) xml_find_all(x, "./tag") |>  xml_attrs()) |> 
  map(bind_rows) |> 
  list_rbind(names_to = "relation") |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = k, values_from = v) 

relation_tags
#> # A tibble: 239 × 37
#>    relation name  operator plant:output:electri…¹ `plant:source` power `repd:id`
#>    <chr>    <chr> <chr>    <chr>                  <chr>          <chr> <chr>    
#>  1 6949501  Tangy SSE      18.7 MW                wind           plant 3467     
#>  2 8384695  Slie… Platina  54 MW                  wind           plant <NA>     
#>  3 8555637  Coom… <NA>     8.5 MW                 wind           plant <NA>     
#>  4 9195703  Bool… Brookfi… 30 MW                  wind           plant <NA>     
#>  5 9196204  Ball… Greenco… 48.3 MW                wind           plant <NA>     
#>  6 9285446  Gruig <NA>     25 MW                  wind           plant 3241     
#>  7 9285684  Creg… Gaelect… 13.8 MW                wind           plant 4653     
#>  8 9296897  Loug… B9 / Re… 10.5 MW                wind           plant 4680     
#>  9 9296910  Bin … <NA>     9 MW                   wind           plant 3113     
#> 10 9298972  Alta… <NA>     26 MW                  wind           plant 3575     
#> # ℹ 229 more rows
#> # ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​`plant:output:electricity`
#> # ℹ 30 more variables: site <chr>, type <chr>, `plant:method` <chr>,
#> #   wikidata <chr>, wikipedia <chr>, alt_name <chr>, fixme <chr>, owner <chr>,
#> #   start_date <chr>, `operator:wikidata` <chr>, `operator:wikipedia` <chr>,
#> #   website <chr>, turbines <chr>, note <chr>, `alt_name:en` <chr>,
#> #   `name:en` <chr>, `name:ga` <chr>, old_operator <chr>, old_website <chr>, …

Form here you can for example join relation_nodes to osm_points object and create MULTIPOINTs of relations:
wind_multipoint_sf <- 
  wind_sf$osm_points |> 
  inner_join(relation_nodes, by = join_by(osm_id == ref)) |> 
  group_by(relation) |> 
  summarise()
wind_multipoint_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 239 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -10.10166 ymin: 51.62229 xmax: -5.656859 ymax: 55.5659
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 239 × 2
#>    relation                                                             geometry
#>    <chr>                                                          <GEOMETRY [°]>
#>  1 10102897                                           POINT (-6.186668 54.93249)
#>  2 10664357 MULTIPOINT ((-8.635368 53.12872), (-8.63826 53.12859), (-8.634468 5…
#>  3 11113896 MULTIPOINT ((-6.365975 52.17676), (-6.363355 52.17386), (-6.360543 …
#>  4 11113897 MULTIPOINT ((-8.226164 54.13107), (-8.228405 54.13296), (-8.231114 …
#>  5 11113898 MULTIPOINT ((-7.79886 52.52894), (-7.795786 52.5316), (-7.771544 52…
#>  6 11198793 MULTIPOINT ((-7.303677 54.92539), (-7.310983 54.92871), (-7.3077 54…
#>  7 11198794 MULTIPOINT ((-7.26855 54.91813), (-7.25883 54.91843), (-7.258841 54…
#>  8 11198795 MULTIPOINT ((-6.744441 54.94007), (-6.748539 54.93631), (-6.745422 …
#>  9 12864417 MULTIPOINT ((-6.257705 55.03091), (-6.256246 55.02987), (-6.254009 …
#> 10 12864418 MULTIPOINT ((-6.44266 55.0026), (-6.450407 55.0003), (-6.450604 54.…
#> # ℹ 229 more rows

Or perhaps just join both relation_nodes & relation_tags frames to points sf object:

wind_joined_sf <- 
  wind_sf$osm_points |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  st_as_sf() |> 
  inner_join(relation_nodes, by = join_by(osm_id == ref)) |> 
  relocate(relation:role, .after = 1) |> 
  left_join(relation_tags, by = "relation") |> 
  janitor::remove_empty()
#> value for "which" not specified, defaulting to c("rows", "cols")

wind_joined_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 2578 features and 88 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -10.10166 ymin: 51.62229 xmax: -5.656859 ymax: 55.5659
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 2,578 × 89
#>    osm_id    relation type.x role      name.x base_height check_date colour
#>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>       <chr>      <chr> 
#>  1 370577265 15261309 node   generator <NA>   <NA>        <NA>       <NA>  
#>  2 370577267 15261309 node   generator <NA>   <NA>        <NA>       <NA>  
#>  3 410873377 14995512 node   generator <NA>   <NA>        <NA>       <NA>  
#>  4 410873379 14995512 node   generator <NA>   <NA>        <NA>       <NA>  
#>  5 410873382 14995512 node   generator <NA>   <NA>        <NA>       <NA>  
#>  6 410873383 14995512 node   generator <NA>   <NA>        <NA>       <NA>  
#>  7 432678296 14175147 node   generator <NA>   <NA>        <NA>       <NA>  
#>  8 885438777 14170264 node   generator <NA>   <NA>        <NA>       <NA>  
#>  9 885438788 14170264 node   generator <NA>   <NA>        <NA>       <NA>  
#> 10 885438789 14170264 node   generator <NA>   <NA>        <NA>       <NA>  
#> # ℹ 2,568 more rows
#> # ℹ 81 more variables: construction <chr>,
#> #   `construction:generator:method` <chr>,
#> #   `construction:generator:output:electricity` <chr>,
#> #   `construction:generator:source` <chr>, `construction:generator:type` <chr>,
#> #   `construction:power.x` <chr>, designation <chr>, `disused:power.x` <chr>,
#> #   fixme.x <chr>, `generator:height` <chr>, `generator:manufacturer` <chr>, …

glimpse(wind_joined_sf)
#> Rows: 2,578
#> Columns: 89
#> $ osm_id                                      <chr> "370577265", "370577267", …
#> $ relation                                    <chr> "15261309", "15261309", "1…
#> $ type.x                                      <chr> "node", "node", "node", "n…
#> $ role                                        <chr> "generator", "generator", …
#> $ name.x                                      <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ base_height                                 <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ check_date                                  <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ colour                                      <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ construction                                <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `construction:generator:method`             <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `construction:generator:output:electricity` <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `construction:generator:source`             <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `construction:generator:type`               <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `construction:power.x`                      <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ designation                                 <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `disused:power.x`                           <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ fixme.x                                     <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `generator:height`                          <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `generator:manufacturer`                    <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `generator:method`                          <chr> "wind_turbine", "wind_turb…
#> $ `generator:output:electricity`              <chr> "0.85 MW", "0.85 MW", "1.3…
#> $ `generator:source`                          <chr> "wind", "wind", "wind", "w…
#> $ `generator:type`                            <chr> "horizontal_axis", "horizo…
#> $ has_aeronautical_lights                     <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ height                                      <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `height:hub`                                <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `height:range`                              <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ man_made                                    <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ manufacturer.x                              <chr> "Vestas", "Vestas", "Norde…
#> $ `manufacturer:type`                         <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `manufacturer:wikidata`                     <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ model                                       <chr> "V52", "V52", "N60", "N60"…
#> $ `monitoring:weather`                        <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ note.x                                      <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ old_operator.x                              <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ old_website.x                               <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ operator.x                                  <chr> "Tornado Electrical Ltd", …
#> $ `operator:website.x`                        <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `operator:wikidata.x`                       <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `operator:wikipedia.x`                      <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ owner.x                                     <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ power.x                                     <chr> "generator", "generator", …
#> $ ref                                         <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `repd:id.x`                                 <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `rotor:diameter`                            <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `rotor:swept_area`                          <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ source.x                                    <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `source:position`                           <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ start_date.x                                <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `tower:construction`                        <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `tower:type`                                <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ year_of_construction.x                      <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ geometry                                    <POINT [°]> POINT (-7.344967 52.…
#> $ name.y                                      <chr> "Beallough Wind Farm", "Be…
#> $ operator.y                                  <chr> "Tornado Electrical Ltd", …
#> $ `plant:output:electricity`                  <chr> "1.7 MW", "1.7 MW", "7.7 M…
#> $ `plant:source`                              <chr> "wind", "wind", "wind", "w…
#> $ power.y                                     <chr> "plant", "plant", "plant",…
#> $ `repd:id.y`                                 <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ site                                        <chr> "wind_farm", "wind_farm", …
#> $ type.y                                      <chr> "site", "site", "site", "s…
#> $ `plant:method`                              <chr> "wind_turbine", "wind_turb…
#> $ wikidata                                    <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ wikipedia                                   <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ alt_name                                    <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ fixme.y                                     <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ owner.y                                     <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ start_date.y                                <chr> "2008", "2008", NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `operator:wikidata.y`                       <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `operator:wikipedia.y`                      <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ website                                     <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ turbines                                    <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ note.y                                      <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `alt_name:en`                               <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `name:en`                                   <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `name:ga`                                   <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ old_operator.y                              <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ old_website.y                               <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ year_of_construction.y                      <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ source.y                                    <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `disused:power.y`                           <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ end_date                                    <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `construction:power.y`                      <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `operator:website.y`                        <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ phone                                       <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `contact:facebook`                          <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ old_name                                    <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ description                                 <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ manufacturer.y                              <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…

Created on 2024-07-17 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks for this brilliant response- it is outstanding! Thanks so much!!!!
